# AngularJS nested directives, inner directive's ng-click is not firing

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

This is a problem I'm having in my app and I am about to reproduce it in a simple example:

```
<div f-outer>
    <div f-inner dat="dat">
        <a href="javascript:" ng-click="run(dat, $event)">
            Click Me
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Clicking "Click Me", I'd expect the `run` function defined on the `f-inner` directive to execute. But it's not.

```
.directive('fOuter', function () {
    return {
        link: function (scope) {
            scope.dat = { x: 1, y: 2 };
            console.log('fOuter.link');
        }
    };
})

.directive('fInner', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            dat: '='
        },
        link: function (scope) {
            console.log('fInner.link');
            scope.run = function (dat, $event) {
                console.log('fInner.scope.run()', dat, $event);
            };
        }
    };
})
```

I also

Here's the example:

http://jsfiddle.net/5QtJs/2/

I also added translude with no luck:

```
transclude: true,
template: "<div ng-transclude></div>",
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5QtJs/3/

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right track with using transclude, presuming you want to include arbitrary content. In your example transclude is unnecessary. The ng-click call you are making is not finding your 'run' method in your directive. (Since, run is used in angular modules, I would advise against using in code). I've refactored your directive below.

```
<div ng-controller="Ctrl3">
  <div f-outer>
      <div f-inner dat="data">Will not show since using 'replace'</div>
  </div>
</div>

.directive('fOuter', function () {
  return {
      link: function (scope) {
          scope.dat = { x: 1, y: 2 };
          console.log('fOuter.link');
      }
  };
})
.directive('fInner', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        replace: true,
        scope: {
            dat: '='
        },
        template: '<div>' +  
                    '<a ng-click="run(dat, $event)">Click Me</a>' +
                  '</div>',
        link: function (scope) {
            console.log('fInner.link');
            scope.run = function (dat, $event) {
                console.log('fInner.scope.run()', dat, $event);
            };
        }
    };
});
```